# do docker container IPs change on restart?

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am new to docker and I have been dockerizing all my application in a single server. So far, everything is fine and working. However, I don't understand one thing. I am using docker-compose for everything (I haven't created dockerfile for my projects yet) and there is this `ports` attribute in docker-compose. If I write something like this:

```
ports:
    8085:80
```

It will listen on 0.0.0.0:8085, which means outside world has access to my server. After some discussions and google-ing, I found that I can take an IP address in my docker bridge network and do port mappings easily:

```
ports:
    172.17.0.1:8085:80
```

This will listen only on 172.17.0.1:8085, which is great as it is only listens on internally and my nginx proxies the traffic to the necessary ports. (e.g `proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8085`). After knowing more about docker and understanding how they work, I realized that all these containers have their own IP addresses with ports exposed only to those addresses. For example, one of my "web" containers has IPv4 address of 172.17.0.10 and port 80 is exposed. If I do `docker inspect` on one of these containers, I will see the IP address of the container.

Now, I want to use these IP addresses in my nginx. Instead of `proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8085`, I want to do `http://172.17.0.10`. I personally think that this is a much elegant interface but there is one thing that concerns me. What happens if I restart my machine? All the containers will start in some kind of order. If I have 5 web containers and they start in random order, can I be sure that the IPs for these containers will be the same? Or will they change? Should I always use `ports` in docker-compose for use by nginx? If yes, how can I have different IPs per container instead of different ports with the same IP? Will it be okay if I create another docker network interface (let's say in subnet 172.17.1.0), and assign different IPs from that interface to the exposed "public" ports? By this I mean basically using `172.17.1.1:80:80` in one container, `172.17.1.2:80:80` in another etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an expert in the docker-networking domain but I'll try my best to answer the questions you got there.

**Q:** What happens if I restart my machine? All the containers will start in some kind of order.
**A:** Unless you use the `links` or `depends_on` keywords, otherwise you cannot guarantee the start sequence.

**Q:** If I have 5 web containers and they start in random order, can I be sure that the IPs for these containers will be the same? 
**A:** I did a little experiment on my machine by taking note of the ipaddresses of my  existing 2 containers (postgresDB and influxDB).

They are running on

1. Postgres: 172.17.0.2
2. InfluxDB: 172.17.0.3

Shut it down and boot again. Probably due to them booting up the same order this time, the ip addresses seems to have been maintained. Added the `depends_on` keyword to force the InfluxDB container to start first before Postgres can, now the IP addresses of both containers are;

1. Postgres: 172.17.0.3
2. InfluxDB: 172.17.0.2

I think the IP is distributed based on a first come first serve basis. If you didn't specify an ordering for booting up the containers I think there is a small chance which the ip can be different for the containers. Really depends on who runs first.

**Q:** Should I always use ports in docker-compose for use by nginx? 
**A:** Yes, if you would like to port forward an nginx instance's port to the outside world. Otherwise no one will be able to hit that web server. E.g. exposing port `443` to let `HTTPs` traffic come through.

**Q:** how can I have different IPs per container instead of different ports with the same IP? 
**A:** I don't know whether that is possible or not but after doing some research for you on the docker-compose documentation it seems possible by using the `ipam` keyword.

**See:**
 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ipam

That looks scary to me so what I did for my own project was to use the `service_name` instead.

**Example:**

```
container_bbb:
    image: banana

my_nginx:
    image: apple
    environment:
      - MOUNT_SRC0=http://container_bbb:80
      - MOUNT_DEST0=/
    links:
      - container_bbb
```

For this instance in the `my_nginx` container, the service name `container_bbb` would be resolved into the hostname of that container. 
Then I will have a python script that would dynamically generate the ngix config using this information at the container's entrypoint script area.

Sounds a bit overkill but that gives me more control over what I want to do with my nginx.

So in my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default-locations/` the configs would be something like;

```
location /container_bbb/ {
    proxy_pass http://container_bbb:3000/;
}
```

**Note:**
I am using this nginx server instance as a reverse proxy server.

I guess what I am trying to say here is that you can essentially use the hostname instead of the ip address. And to get to the container next-door you would pass in `http://CONTAINER_SERVICE_NAME:PORT`

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on the containers' IP addresses. If all your services are on the same docker-compose config, they will automatically be part of the same internal network and you can simply use the service names as the hostnames.

E.g., If your web app was named `php`, your nginx proxy config would look something like:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass  http://php;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_redirect     off;
}
```

(Also note you might want to enable your firewall, just in case any of the port mappings leaks out to the public IP address of the host.)

Comment: That is correct answer but there is a poblem you will face when the php container restarting, it may take different ip than nginx cache the php ip resolvation from dns.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/722438/nginx-refresh-upstream-server-ip about nginx picking up changing hostname.